# Need to ping BLE device to check if alive from windows

Tags: windows

So far i have no clue were to start.
I need a way to ping a Linux BLE device to check if it's alive.

Just like i would use the ping command in CMD, just for Bluetooth instead.

Comment: You could start a scan to see if it's advertising.

Comment: But again how do i do that. Is there any built in functions to scan, or do i need third party software for this?

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/bluetooth/example/19735/listen-for-a-bluetooth-le-advertisement